# Trigger property set when editing a member of that property

Tags: c#, properties

I have an Angle class which has 2 properties (Degree and Radians). 
Then in another class I have an Angle property with a get and set accessor. Is there a way to trigger the set of that property when setting a property of Angle?

```
public Angle RotationAngle
{
  get { return _rotationAngle; }
  set
  {
    //this should trigger when setting RoationAngle.Deg
  }
}
private Angle _rotationAngle;

RotationAngle.Deg = 5;
```

Comment: Try making Angle Immutable, then you need to assign Angle every time not modifying it's fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a bad design choice, you don't usually expect that setting the value of one property should also set the value of another.

I suppose you could try this though.

Create a constructor on `Angle`:

```
public Angle(float deg, float rad)
{
    this.Deg = deg;
    this.Rad = rad;
}
```

Have an auto property on the `Angle` class and set that whenever `Deg` gets set:

```
public float Deg
{
    get
    {
        return _deg;
    }
    set
    {
        _deg = value;
        this.RotationAngle = new Angle(value, _rad);
    }
}

public Angle RotationAngle
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

You can then access `RotationAngle` from the other class.

Alternatively, you could look into the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, and fire an event when `Deg` gets set, e.g:

```
public class Angle : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private float _deg;
    private float _rad;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Angle() { }

    public Angle(float deg, float rad)
    {
        this.Deg = deg;
        this.Rad = rad;
    }

    public float Deg
    {
        get
        {
            return _deg;
        }
        set
        {
            _deg = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Deg");
        }
    }

    public float Rad
    {
        get
        {
            return _rad;
        }
        set
        {
            _rad = value;
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Then, in your other class, you would subscribe to the event when you create the `Angle` instance and set `RotationAngle` when the event is fired:

```
Angle angle = new Angle();   
angle.PropertyChanged += angle_PropertyChanged;

static void angle_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
     // You would set `RotationAngle` here
     this.RotationAngle = foo;
}
```